# Python: import csv files, set dict name as filename, headers as keys, and columns as values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas

I have a directory containing folders and inside each folder is about 20 CSV files, each with a different file name; files contain columns A, B, C, D, E and each column contains numerical data (some entries are NaN). What I want is each filename to be the name of a dictionary, where A, B, C, D, E are keys in that dictionary, and the data below are the values to those keys.

as an example:

```
A  B  C  D  E
0  3  6  1  6
1  6  1  0  5
3  4  9  8  5
7  6  4  0  9
```

the numbers in these columns are not necessary int, if that matters.

I think I figured out how to set the dict name as filename with a for-loop, that is:

```
rootDir = 'path'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
     for fname in FileList
        fname = {} #I think this makes each dictionary have the same name as the file
```

I found a way to read in the values from the csvs using http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/

that is,

```
filepath = os.path.join(rootDir, dirName, fname)
var = pd.read_csv(filepath, na_values=str) #reads in NaN values
```

Ideally this will read in the CSVs one at a time.

But I'm not sure how this will help me. I took a look at the pandas Dataframe.to_dict() but I don't think the above code reads into a dataframe (or, if it does, I don't understand the documentation well enough). It looks like it'll only store one value per key at a time. Another thread I was reading says it's possible to store more than one value per key, though (using .append() ) but I don't know how to apply it to this situation.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do the first part - "each filename to be the name of a dictionary" - without some really dark magic. And no, your first code sample does not actually work :) And if it worked it would be a really bad idea - consider a directory containing files named `sys`, `os` etc. :)

But you can nest dictionaries inside dictionaries, which more or less achieves what you want, only with slightly different syntax:

```
rootDir = 'path'
my_csvs = {}
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
    for fname in FileList
        my_csvs[fname] = {}
```

(for the "how to read a csv file" part refer to the @rofls's answer who posted a bit quicker than me)

Comment: Supposing the directory would never contain files with those names (it wouldn't)... is it just really bad practice to do something like this?

Would there be any issues with RAM if I did something this way? The CSVs are really huge.

Comment: What if I named each dictionary ticker_fname, where fname is whatever file python is trying to read in on that loop instance? I heard eval() can do some dark magic and renaming like this should avoid any conflicts. 

I tried 

    eval('ticker_ %s' % fname = {})

but obviously it doesn't work ;)

Comment: Yes, it would be a really bad, unexpected and unusual practice, and yes, you can use eval to do this (I guess), and no, it would not affect performance or memory consumption too much

Comment: i'd rather not have to load in that massive dictionary every time I wanted to access it, though; it would be easier for me just to call individual dictionaries. I read up on eval() and exec() and I can see how there can be dangers in using it. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
import os, csv

rootDir = 'path'
items = {}
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False):
    for fname in fileList:
        with open(os.path.join(dirName,fname),'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                try:
                    items[fname].append(row)
                except KeyError:
                    items[fname] = list()

print items
```

Answer (score 0):

### The code

This works:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'path'
data = {}
for root, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in file_names:
        full_file_name = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        data[file_name] = pd.read_csv(full_file_name, delim_whitespace=True).to_dict(orient='list')
```

Walk down your paths with `os.path.walk` and use pandas.
You need to create the full path, otherwise pandas cannot find the file because the file is not in the current working directory.

You need to tell `pd.read_csc()` to use white space as delimiter. The method `to_dict(orient='list')` converts the data frame into a dictionary with th column names as keys and a list of float values. Pandas takes care of NaNs.

If you get deeper into pandas, you might want to keep the data frames without converting them to dictionaries. For example, this line:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

gives you this data frame:

[image]

It allows a lot of sophisticated operations.

### The sample data

`file1.txt`:

```
A  B  C  D  E
0  3  6  1  6
1  6  1  0  5
3  4  9  8  5
7  6  4  0  9
7  6  NaN  0  9
```

`file2.txt`:

```
A  B  C  D  E
0  3  6  1  6
7  6  NaN  0  9
```

### The output

Now `data` contains:

```
{'file1.txt': {'A': [0, 1, 3, 7, 7],
  'B': [3, 6, 4, 6, 6],
  'C': [6.0, 1.0, 9.0, 4.0, nan],
  'D': [1, 0, 8, 0, 0],
  'E': [6, 5, 5, 9, 9]},
 'file2.txt': {'A': [0, 7],
  'B': [3, 6],
  'C': [6.0, nan],
  'D': [1, 0],
  'E': [6, 9]}}
```